# If my iOS app requires a company name should i a) transfer accounts or b) create a new account?

Tags: ios, xcode

This post has nothing to do with code. But it kind of does.

There are a couple of posts on this topic but from a while back.
I have recently submitted an iOS app to the app store for review.
And the issue is that the account name is under my personal name.
The account name needs to be the same name as the app. I confirmed this with Apple. Assuming I get all the business registration sorted and DUNS number etc. i have the following questions.

1. I have a couple of apps already under my personal name in the account. Am I better off deleting these apps and leaving my current app and migrating the account over from personal -> company?

Or should I just open a new account entirely with the company? (there is a fee of course).

2. If I do open a new account I will obviously need to re-submit a binary. This new binary will need a new certificate, etc. What do I do with the bundle id in xcode?

I will effectively have an app under my personal account with a bundle ID of xxx.yyy.com that was rejected.

And then I will open a company account. I'm assuming I can't just upload a new binary with the same bundle id.

If you change the bundle identifier under the General->Identity tab in xcode - does that affect other parts of the program?

3. If an app has been rejected during the review process on the app store and has never made it to being accepted - does it need to be deleted?

Thanks

Comment: I do not believe you can rename your account to the company's. You could create a new account for the company and delete yours though.

Comment: *"This post has nothing to do with code"* and is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thx @pqnet but one option is to migrate your personal account to a company account. You still need all the same paperwork though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company that I work for was on the same spot last year.

What we decided to do was create a new account for the company. The fee was paid by the company and configured by them ( DUNS number and contact info ) with our help.

I'm not sure if you can migrate your personal account to a company account. If it was possible, you will have to delete your other apps, which seems a big sacrifice.

The downside of this is that you will need a new bundle ID (it will not affect any part of your code, you can change it as much as you want in development, the problem arises when you upload your app to the Appstore). You'll just create a new bundle ID and re-submit.

What you can do if that is an issue is upload your app to your personal account, publish it and then transfer it to the company account.

Comment: Thx @Nick. Could you just elaborate on "the downside of this is that you will need a new bundle ID (it will not affect any part of your code, you can change it as much as you want in development, the problem arises when you upload your app to the Appstore)." Right now I have an app in my personal account that has been rejected. it has never been approved. It's bundle id is com.jmxxx.yyy.zzz.  If I create a new company account and change my bundle id to com.jmxxx.aaa.bbb why would there be a problem uploading the binary to the company account?

Comment: Once you create a bundle ID and submit it to the AppStore it’s reserved for your account and app only. What I meant it will be a problem if you used the same one, if you change it won’t be a problem :)